# How to insert my personal validation data in MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's consider data following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(1.0, 0.005, 100)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
x_train = x[0:80]
x_valid = x[81:100]
y_train = y[0:80]
y_valid = y[81:100]
```

Now I want to apply `MLPRegressor` to fit model which predicts `y` using `x`. I want to use `(x_train, y_train)` as train data and `(x_valid, y_valid)` as validation data.

How can I do it? I couldn't find any option in `MLPRegressor` to provide my own valiation data. The only option I found is `validation_fraction` but it will split it randomly, not as I want - first 80% of observations as training and last 20% as validation. Is there any option to do so?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not.

Comment: Also, can you maybe explain why you necessarily need the first 80% for validation and not a random partition of 80%?

Comment: It's necessary when you I'm dealing with data with time dimension.

Comment: Use `shuffle=False` with `validation_fraction`. Please refer https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html